Не появляется кнопка в тг боте
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = (types.InlineKeyboardButton('Покупка', callback_data='Покупка'))
    markup.row(btn1)
    bot.reply_to(message, '✅ ДОБРО ПОЖАЛОВАТЬ В BINGO SHOP!\n\n Преимущества нашего сервиса:\n\nОгромный выбор городов по всей стране\n\nВыгодные цены и высочайшее качество товара.\n\nОгромный опыт работы в данной сфере.',reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'Покупка':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Выберите город')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Москва', callback_data='Москва'))
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Выберите город', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'Москва':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Выберите товар')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)


Попробуйте btn1 указать не в кортеже. Уберите лишние скобки.

а какие скобки здесь лишние? я не разбираюсь я просто по гайду с ютуба это пишу

btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Покупка', callback_data='Покупка')

все равно не работает

Сбрось токен у бота в BotFather и замени в коде на новый. Не поверишь, но это действительно так решается: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/discussions/2097#discussioncomment-7811228

не помогло, попробовал 3 раза

Тогда без понятия, код полностью корректный
